# Visualize a web page on raspberry OS Lite

Tags: raspbian-lite, web-browsers

I need to print into a web page the data stored into a raspberry. The problem is that I can't connect the raspberry to the internet so I have to check this web page in localhost. The micro SD (4GB) where I have the OS can only store the Lite version, so is there any way to show at least a browser window to see this webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lynx is a text-based browser. You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt install lynx
```